# Converting SQL query to LINQ - four tables

Tags: sql, linq

I'm not usually bad with LINQ but this one is giving me a headache.
Need fresh minds to take a look.

I've got four tables

```
Task         Account       AcctUserXref      User
-----        -------       ------------      -----
TaskID       AcctID        UserID (fk)       UserID
AcctNumber   AcctNumber    AcctID (fk)       UserName
```

I'm trying to find all Tasks based on the UserName.
Here's the snippet from the SQL statement I'm trying to convert.

```
SELECT @cntTask = Count(TaskID) 
FROM Task tsk, Account acct, AcctUserXref acx
WHERE tsk.AcctNumber = acct.AcctNumber
AND acct.AcctID = acx.AcctID
AND acx.AcctID IN (SELECT acx2.AcctID
                   FROM AcctUserXref acx2, User usr
                   WHERE acx2.UserID = usr.UserID
                   AND usr.UserName = @UserName)
```

How do I directly convert this to LINQ? Or if there's a better way to implement in LINQ what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why your query doesn't look like that:

```
SELECT @cntTask = Count(TaskID) 
FROM Task tsk, Account acct, AcctUserXref acx, User usr
WHERE tsk.AcctNumber = acct.AcctNumber
AND acct.AcctID = acx.AcctID
AND acx.UserID = usr.UserID
AND usr.UserName = @UserName
```

LINQ equivalent:

```
var numberOfTasks = (from u in Users
                     join au in AccountsToUsers on u.UserId equals au.UserId
                     join a in Accounts on au.AcctID equals a.AcctID
                     join t in Tasks on a.AcctNumber equals t.AcctNumber
                     where u.UserName == "NameYoureLookingFor").Count();
```

Comment: This works great! I didn't write the query, but you're right, this is much simpler. I'll pass it along. Thanks!